# Does variable of Abstract Class contains jump pointer

Tags: c++

For example :

```
   class A
   {
    virtual int foo()=0;
    virtual int foo1() = 0;
    virtual int foo2() = 0;
   };
```

I know abstract class have vtable but vtable contains any information(jump pointer to function).
I think it must be null or  go to nothing.

Because i can't instantiate alone i cant check from memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo()=0;
    virtual void foo1() = 0;
    virtual void foo2() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "foo"; }
    virtual void foo1() { std::cout << "foo1"; }
    virtual void foo2() { std::cout << "foo2"; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B b;    //add a breakpoint on this line.
    return 0;
}
```

Open the assemble view and debug step by step

```
001D153E  lea         ecx,[b] 
001D1541  call        B::B (1D113Bh)  //step into

B::B
001D15B0  push        ebp  
001D15B1  mov         ebp,esp 
001D15B3  sub         esp,0CCh 
001D15B9  push        ebx  
001D15BA  push        esi  
001D15BB  push        edi  
001D15BC  push        ecx  
001D15BD  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh] 
001D15C3  mov         ecx,33h 
001D15C8  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
001D15CD  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
001D15CF  pop         ecx  
001D15D0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx 
001D15D3  mov         ecx,dword ptr [this] 
001D15D6  call        A::A (1D1140h)   //step into
....

A::A
001D1730  push        ebp  
001D1731  mov         ebp,esp 
001D1733  sub         esp,0CCh 
001D1739  push        ebx  
001D173A  push        esi  
001D173B  push        edi  
001D173C  push        ecx  
001D173D  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh] 
001D1743  mov         ecx,33h 
001D1748  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
001D174D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
001D174F  pop         ecx  
001D1750  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx 
001D1753  mov         eax,dword ptr [this] 
001D1756  mov         dword ptr [eax],offset A::`vftable' (1D782Ch) 
001D175C  mov         eax,dword ptr [this]
```

1D782Ch is the address of A::vftable,which stores three same address.

Answer (score -1):

If some methods don't have body ( `= 0` ), they are called pure virtual functions.

A class cannot be instanciated if it has pure virtuals.

What you need to do is create a child class that implements those methods

```
   class B : public A
   {
    virtual int foo(){}
    virtual int foo1(){}
    virtual int foo2(){}
   };
```

EDIT :

If you really want to know about the content of the vtable at that point, here is a [related article](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/pure_virtual.html)

Comment: You have no idea what @Oribit is asking about.